# Bad request requsição http post angular

Tags: json, angular, http-request

AO realizar uma requisição http post, estou recebendo:

Object { headers: {…}, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "[https://endereçoocultado](https://endere%C3%A7oocultado)", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for [https://endereçoocultado](https://endere%C3%A7oocultado) 400 Bad Request", error: {…} }

Meu serviço que envia o post:

```
  pesquisaEmail(email): Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');

    return this._http.post<any>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT_EMAIL,
      {email: email,
      token_jc: this.token },
      { headers: headers, observe: 'response' })
        .pipe(
          map((response) => ({data: response.body, status: response.status}))
        )}
```

minha api do backend espera uma chave email com o email e outra chave token com valor do token que é armazenado no localstorage.
Porque recebo um bad request?

Comment: E o erro ocultado? `error: {…}`

Comment: error: {…}
​​
contaMP1: null
​​
contaMP2: null
​​
contaMP3: null
​​
contas: Array []
​​
modulos: Array []
​​
plano: "Trial"
​​
whatsapp: null
​​
__proto__: {…}

Comment: são os campos e valores que a api deveria me retornar preenchida